# What is the word to describe languages that have classes and inheritance?

Tags: object-oriented, terminology

What is the word used to describe the type of programming languages that provide explicit syntax for defining classes and that support inheritance?

For example: "A ______ language, such as C++, Java, C#, or D."

I keep thinking "object oriented", but that also includes languages like Lua and JavaScript, which aren't quite what I'm thinking of.

I am sure there is a definitive term for this group of languages, I just do not know what it is.

Comment: It is object oriented. That is the definition of object oriented.

Comment: maybe your thinking of polymorphism? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid I'm actually looking for a subset of "object-oriented", but I think I found it; looking at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FDetails_of_the_Object_Model), it seems there may not be one nice clean word, but the phrase I'm looking for is "class based object oriented" (vs. prototype based).

Comment: It kind of makes sense but I have never felt the need to make the distinction. I'll check out the article though =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Class-based object-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) language

> Class-based programming, or more commonly class-orientation, is a style of object-oriented programming (OOP) in which inheritance is achieved by defining classes of objects, as opposed to the objects themselves ([compare prototype-based programmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)g).

Answer (score 3):

Classes and inheritance are completely orthogonal to OO. There are languages with classes that aren't object-oriented, there are languages with inheritance that aren't object-oriented, there are languages which are object-oriented and have classes but not inheritance, there are languages which are object-oriented and have inheritance but no classes, and there are languages which are object-oriented and have neither inheritance nor classes.

A common term for languages like Smalltalk is "class-based object-oriented language" (which silently implies inheritance between classes). However, this doesn't apply to languages like Java or C#, because here, object-oriented programming isn't done with classes but with interfaces. In Java or C#, classes describe Abstract Data Types, not Objects, interfaces describe Objects. (See [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/))

So, the best you can probably do is "language with class-based inheritance", which is sometimes also referred to as "classical inheritance".

Comment: It would be nice to include an example of each language from the first paragraph.